# Document editing API in iOS application

Tags: ios

I've an application which requires editing documents of type (doc, docx, ppt, pptx and txt). Apple has a built in framework to view the contents of the documents but I couldn't find any support to edit these documents.

It would be great if someone can help me out if there are any third party frameworks either open source or licensed versions which we can integrate it in our application. This should have a support to highlight text in the above mentioned formats.

Any approach to solve this requirements can help me a lot.

Thanks
Sudheer

Comment: Not easy I'm afraid: viewing is simple (UIWebView will do it) but even the newer Open Office XML format (e.g. .docx) is hard to edit. However, LibreOffice and OpenOffice.org manage it fine. You could start by examining their source and maybe build a library from their code (if the license is acceptable.)

Comment: Hey Tim, thanks for the reply. I'll try out with the way you have mentioned.

Comment: Is there any other way where we have an already built-in API support for iOS (be it a free or a licensed version) which we can directly integrate it in our application because it's just a small requirement in our application where we can highlight text of doc, docx, ppt, pptx and txt formats. I'm even touch basing with LibreOffice regarding this.